# MySQL alternatives to binary auto-increment column?

Tags: php, mysql, web, binary, auto-increment

MySQL has [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) which allows us to create unique primary keys automatically.

However, this only works for integer columns. There doesn't seem to be a way to combine `auto_increment` with [`binary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) columns, for example:

```
mysql > create table Users(Id binary(6) auto_increment, primary key(id));

#1063 - Incorrect column specifier for column 'Id'
```

How can we create or implement an auto-increment binary column?

(Finding a solution which maintains atomicity and have comparable performance to `auto_increment` integer columns.)

Comment: probably a before-insert trigger to calculate the new id value in a transaction-safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger that is called before each insert operation should be safe for transactions and will accomplish what you want.

Checkout the [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) on triggers.

Comment: I believe that triggers are fully supported on InnoDB tables, yes.

Comment: Misunderstood you. No, I do not know if atomicity is guaranteed, though from brief googling it appears that the before update trigger is atomic. Having said that, if you are going to go this route, you should absolutely test on a small database before use.

Comment: Hmm, but it doesn't seem to be acidly safe to use triggers as a replacement for auto-increment, from http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3409/9405 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881043/are-database-triggers-safe-for-cross-table-integrity-constraints/16881199#16881199