# Are database triggers safe for cross table integrity constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, transactions

I suggested using a trigger to check a cross table integrity constraint answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16878683/2032064). It has been suggested in the comments that it may cause problems:

> Triggers to do cross row checks rarely work on most databases ... because they cannot read uncommitted rows from other transactions

I haven't found any source supporting the claim, though. [Official](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_triggers.htm#autoId3) [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions) doesn't mention anything. Others issues I found are covered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/460316/2032064) - it mostly criticizes potential hidden complexity as triggers are not visible on first sight. But even the [highest rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460343/2032064) admits their usage for integrity issues.

So my question is: **Are database triggers safe for cross table integrity constraints?** Specifically, would the solution below work?

---

To summarize the original question. We have tables

- Player - PlayerID, PlayerName
- Bet  - BetID, BetName
- plays_in - BetID, PlayerID

The constraint is that the combination of BetName and PlayerID should be unique. Definition of the suggested trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_bet_name BEFORE INSERT ON plays_in 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      DECLARE bet_exists INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);

      SELECT 1 INTO bet_exists 
        FROM Bet AS b1
        WHERE b1.BetID = NEW.BetID
          AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM plays_in AS p JOIN Bet AS b2 USING (BetID)
            WHERE p.PlayerID = NEW.PlayerID AND b2.BetName = b1.BetName
          )
        LIMIT 1;

      IF bet_exists THEN
        SET msg = "Bet name already exists...";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
      END IF;
  END//
```

Comment: Can you run a simple test to check that statement about being unable to see uncommitted changes (which sounds like it should be true)?

Comment: @Thilo oh my, you're right, it really fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **triggers are not safe**.

It turns out that the trigger really doesn't see uncommited changes done in other transactions and passes without an error. It can be demonstrated like this

Transaction 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO plays_in (BetID, PlayerID) VALUES (1,1); -- query A
```

Transaction 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO plays_in (BetID, PlayerID) VALUES (1,2); -- query B; in conflict with A, but passses
```

Both transactions:

```
COMMIT;
```

Now `plays_in` will contains both inserted records even though if A and B were executed in a single transaction, the trigger would throw an error.

The whole example sources can be obained [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f033)

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on which database and how well you write the logic.

Early versions of infomodeler/visiomodeler supported some pretty arcane and complex forms of referential integrity, and provided the code to implement them on several databases. Early versions of Sybase / sql server didn't support declarative referential integrity so all the logic was implemented in triggers - successfully.

I wouldn't take the failure of one implementation of a counter-example as authoritative.